# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields - Meta Query no result

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WPML and ACF in my WP.

Now I wanna list posts from the category ID 399 with the ACF Field "organization_type" and the value key "socialbusiness" but they do not show up.

This are my query tries:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'cat'      => 399,
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'meta_query'        => array(
                //'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'organization_type',
                    'value' => 'socialbusiness',
                    //'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        //unset($args);

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => 399,
            'meta_key' => 'organization_type',
            'meta_value' => 'socialbusiness'
        );

        // query
        query_posts( $args );
        while( have_posts() ) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should have just one variable $args because your first declaration of the variable is override by your second variable.

In your case your code should look like :

```
 <?php
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'category',
         'field' => 'id',
         'terms' => 399
         )
      ),
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
       'key' => 'organization_type',
       'value' => 'socialbusiness',
       'compare' => '=',
       'type' => 'CHAR'
       ),
      )
   );

 $items = new WP_Query($args);
 ?>
 <?php if($items->have_posts()) : ?>
   <div class='item'>
      <?php while($items->have_posts()) : $items->the_post() ?>
         .....
      <?php endwhile ?>
   </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I would love if that works but it also doesn't show any result!! I checked the category ID several times... so frustrating. What can it be?